# Is mv * a destructive command on a directory with 2 or more files? What other linux commands have similar behavior?

Tags: linux, bash

When I run mv * with no destination directory on a directory with say 10 files, I get an error as follows

```
root@tryit-apparent:~/test2# ls                                                                                                                        
file1.txt  file10.txt  file2.txt  file3.txt  file4.txt  file5.txt  file6.txt  file7.txt  file8.txt  file9.txt                                          
root@tryit-apparent:~/test2# mv *                                                                                                                      
mv: target 'file9.txt' is not a directory
```

When I run it on a directory with two files it overwrites the file with one just file.

```
root@tryit-apparent:~/test# ls                                                                                                                         
tempfile  tempfile2                                                                                                                                    
root@tryit-apparent:~/test# mv *                                                                                                                       
root@tryit-apparent:~/test# ls                                                                                                                         
tempfile2
```

I read the man pages but couldn't understand this behaviour. Would like to know what's causing this behavior and what's going on under the hood?

What other linux commands have such pitfalls and have destructive actions that are executed silently if the user is not aware of such behavior?

Comment: `*` in this context is a [shell file name expansion](https://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_04.html). In the first example it expands to `mv file1.txt file10.txt  file2.txt  file3.txt  file4.txt  file5.txt  file6.txt  file7.txt  file8.txt  file9.txt` which is not a valid `mv` command. The second example expands to `mv tempfile1 tempfile2`.

Comment: ahh that makes sense. 
so in the second case it renames tempfile1 as tempfile2 leaving the contents of tempfile1 intact while silently "overwriting" tempfile2 as the file name already exists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Unix, unlike some other OSes, wildcards like `*` are expanded by the shell, *before* being passed to the command being run.  So when you run `mv *` with `tempfile` and `tempfile2` as the only files in the current directory, what the shell actually executes is `mv tempfile tempfile2`, which as normal will rename the first file over the second one, erasing the previous contents of `tempfile2`.  The shell doesn't know or care that this command treats its last argument specially, and `mv` has no way of knowing that its two arguments came from a wildcard expansion.  Hence the behavior you're seeing.

You can have similar issues even with more than two files.  For instance, if you have files named `tempfile1` through `tempfile9` and a subdirectory named `zyzzx`, then `mv *` will move all your temp files into the `zyzzx` subdirectory.

Mostly, you just have to be aware that this is how wildcards work, and use caution with commands that treat one of their arguments specially (e.g. as a destination).  `cp` is another one to watch out for, for the same reason.  For interactive usage, you may want to get used to using the `-i` option to `mv` and `cp`, which asks for confirmation before overwriting files; or use an alias to make this the default.

Answer (score 1):

Move is intented to move or rename a file or a directory, so you need a `source` **and** a destination.

If the path of the file is unchange then it becomes a rename operation.

If the path changes and the name remains the same it's a move.

You can do both by chaning the path and the name.

Man pages can be challenging to wrap your head around.

Googling can help:  https://www.howtoforge.com/linux-mv-command/

Off the top of my head, you could do a `cp` operation followed by a `rm` to achieve similar results, but that's two steps, rather than one.